# How do I select drop down elements implemented with ng-repeat

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, protractor

[my dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o904Z.png)I am facing difficulty in selecting drop down items in protractor automation. These drop down items seems to be getting picked from data base. I am very new to angularjs app automation using protractor.Though I have automated similar drop down item selection, this one if giving me a hard time. Desperately looking for help from the community.

Below is HTML/Angular material code:

```
<md-select style="margin: 0px;" ng-model="vm.companyProfile.rgst_address.state" ng-change="vm.getCities(vm.companyProfile.rgst_address.state)" required="" class="ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" aria-multiselectable="false" id="select_39" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" aria-label="State">
  <md-select-value class="md-select-value md-select-placeholder" id="select_value_label_19">
    <span>State</span>
    <span class="md-select-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </md-select-value>
  <div class="md-select-menu-container" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" id="select_container_40">
    <md-select-menu role="presentation" class="_md">
      <md-content class="_md"><!-- ngRepeat: state in vm.states | orderBy : 'state' -->
        <md-option ng-value="state._id" ng-repeat="state in vm.states | orderBy : 'state'" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_171" aria-checked="true" value="58c7ffd5449b7f21ec914700" style="">
          <div class="md-text ng-binding">Andaman and Nicobar Islands</div>
        </md-option><!-- end ngRepeat: state in vm.states | orderBy : 'state' --> 
        <md-option ng-value="state._id" ng-repeat="state in vm.states | orderBy : 'state'" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_172" aria-checked="true" value="58c7ffd5449b7f21ec914701" style="">
          <div class="md-text ng-binding">Andhra Pradesh</div>
        </md-option><!-- end ngRepeat: state in vm.states | orderBy : 'state' -->

        //etc...

      </md-content>
    </md-select-menu>
  </div>
</md-select>
```

Below is how I tried to code in protractor:

```
browser.findElement(by.model('vm.companyProfile.rgst_address.state')).click();
    browser.driver.sleep(5000);
    browser.findElements(by.repeater('state in vm.states')).then(function (item1) {
        item1[2].click();
        });
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Received below error message:                                                   
       Failed: element not visible
      (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.84)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522940 (1a76f96f66e3ca7b8e57d503b4dd3bccfb
a87af1),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)

Comment: Why using `browser.findElement` instead of just `element`?

Comment: browser.findElement and element both works equally well. Since I am from Selenium background and very new to protractor,I am yet to completely switch to protractor specific commands. I have worked on many drop downs before but the drop down in question is giving me a lot of hard time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { element, by } from 'protractor';

var dropdown = element(by.model('vm.companyProfile.rgst_address.state'));
var dropdownItems = element.all(by.repeater("state in vm.states | orderBy : 'state'"));

dropdown.click().then(() => {
    dropdownItems.get(1).click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need [`by.repeater`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.repeater) in your case, since you don't want to do something with all the listed element and you don't have a complex object that is returned (only a list value). So you probably just want to select one specific element out of the generated list (and you don't need the full collection of all repeated values).

Therefore to select your option to me it sounds like you could make use of the Selector [`cssContainingText()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText). (Note: if you always want to select the i.e. 3rd value OR if you want to count the number of values, for such cases [`by.repeater`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.repeater) would be appropriate).

As for your error: `element not visible` means most probably your dropdown selection is not yet opened (and therefore the option you want to select is not visible).

So you'll probably need to click in the dropdown field first in order to open the dropdown selection (as you would do as real user)

So all in all something like this:

```
//open dropdown selection
element(by.model('vm.companyProfile.rgst_address.state')).click();
//select dropdown value
element(by.cssContainingText('md-option[ng-value="state._id"] div', 'optionYouWantToSelect').click();

//as bonus the use with by.repeater - always select 2nd value
element(by.repeater('state in vm.states').row(1)).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a single line command

element(by.xpath('*//[@id="select_39"]//md-option[contains(text(),"Andaman and Nicobar Islands")]'));

Note : xpaths would differ everytime you change your div. But since the id would remain same I think this would be stable.

Comment: If I am not wrong you are trying just to click an option out of these right? Or would you like to hold the complete list of options in an object?

Comment: The id of the respective option is changing every time we access the page. We just want to click drop down and select an option from the drop down.Clicking drop down and viewing its contents woks fine, but selecting an option from drop down fails.

Comment: Okay I get it. is there any attribute that remains constant and unique for the dropdown?

Comment: Suppose if your model remains constant you can use '*//[@model="vm.companyProfile.rgst_address.state"]//md-option[contains(text(),"Andaman and Nicobar Islands")]'.